# Autocomplete for dynamically created input using jQuery 3.2.1

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I have found autocomplete for dynamically created inputs using jQuery 1.9.1, but I'm using jQuery 3.2.1 (am unable to change the version), kindly give me the solution for jQuery 3.2.1!

The example below is working fine in jQuery 1.9.1:

```
<script>
 var availableTags = {
     source: ["ActionScript", "AppleScript"],
     minLength: 2
 };
 $("#myProd0").autocomplete({
  source:availableTags
});
  </script>

<html>
<input type="text" name="myProd0" id="productname">
</html>
```

If I run the code above in jquery 3.2.1, it says `autocomplete is not a function`.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/6mtYe/ (changing to jQuery v3.1.2 won't work)

Comment: Already tried to google this?

Comment: yes tried more than an hour. couldn't find out the solution

Comment: Atleast give us what you tried. A simple code or something

Answer (score 1):

I think JQuery UI is what you need, check this:

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

If you click on "View source", you'll see an example with jquery version 1.12.4, but if you replace this line:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

for this line:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
```

It still works.

Comment: sorry im getting Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Comment: Hmmm... I don't get any errors... What other JS files are you including? 

Pherhaps one of them is conflicting with your JQuery files, check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591155/autocomplete-is-not-a-function-error

If so, I would recommend to just copy and paste the code of the page I posted and then add your other JS files one by one until it fails, so you can tell which one is creating the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery ui

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="external/jquery/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="external/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var availableTags = {
     source: ["ActionScript", "AppleScript"],
     minLength: 2
  };
  $("#myProd0").autocomplete({
   source:availableTags
  });
</script>
```

check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371754/jquery-3-1-0-and-jquery-ui-autocomplete-are-not-compatible-whats-the-workaroun/41564387)